# Creating a 2D array from a 1D list and plotting as 2D heatmap

Tags: python, arrays, plot

Python beginner here. I'm using numpy and matplotlib.

I have a sinusoidal function that generates a 1D list 100 items wide. I want to turn it into a 2D list/array/matrix that is 100 items wide and 50 items long where each new row of that matrix is identical to the last (numbers here are arbitrary).

I then want to plot this as a greyscale x-y heat map, where the colour is proportional to the number of each index. Something like:

[image]

I generate my 1D array something like this:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    x_array[i] = (np.cos(a[i]))**2 * (np.sinc(b[i]))**2
```

Where a and b are previously defined lists of the same length. I then plot this against n to get a nice 1D line.

Physicists will recognise this is an interference pattern of two slits. I want to add another dimension of any length to be able to plot the fringes in x/y/intensity space.

Is there a simple loop I could implement that 'copies' this list x times, and then a method for me to plot these? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the array you can use list comprehensions:

```
x_matrix=[x_array for i in range(50)]
```

Plotting is harder if you don't have a good package like matplotlib.
Then it is simply

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(x_matrix)`

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my original post to add that I'm using numpy and matplotlib. This works and is a great starting point for me to improve, thanks.

Comment: Oh by the way. If you need it to be black & white use
import matplotlib.cm as cm
plt.imshow(x_matrix, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
plt.show()

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using `numpy` because you mentioned plotting and `matplotlib` seems to be the de-facto standard.  If that is the case, you can just multiply your array by `np.ones(required_shape)` and broadcasting should do what you want ... e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a * np.ones((5, 10))
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

Here I've constructed a 5x10 array from my original array that had length 10.

---

If `x_array` isn't a numpy array to start, it should be pretty easy to make it one:

```
x_array = np.array(x_array)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my original post to say I'm using numpy and matplotlib. This works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array corresponding to an image like you describe, you can simply use NumPy's slice notation to fill all the "rows" with the same values:

```
I = np.zeros((50,100))
I[:] = np.cos(np.pi * d * x / lam)**2 * np.sinc(np.pi * b * x / lam)**2
```